# Keeping UINavigationController's navigationBar hidden after UISearchDisplayController selection

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` setup with a `UITableViewController` which is nested inside a `UINavigationController`.  When a selection of a cell is made, `UITableView's` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is triggered, which pushes a new view to the parent navigation controller.  This new view should have the navigation bar hidden on entry.

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

I use this line in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to hide the navigation bar.  This works fine when a row is selected not using the search controller, but is overridden when selecting a search result.  It seems the `UISearchDisplayController` takes it in its right to un-hide the navigationBar sometime after the row is selected.

If I move the `setNavigationBarHidden` call into the target view's `viewWillAppear` method, results are similar.  I can make it work by placing the hide call in `viewDidAppear`, but this makes for a *very* awkward transition effect which feels jumpy and out of place.  I would like to make the navigationBar already hidden before the new view slides on to the screen.

Does anyone know where the unhiding of the navigationBar is occurring, and/or any way I can override this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry I have not yet marked a correct answer; I did eventually find a hack that worked which is probably the same as one below, but I have since moved on and haven't looked at that project for a while. When I do get a chance I'll check which method I used and update this question.

Comment: Wich hack did you end up using?

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but I believe it does exactly what you'd want it to.  I came across a similar problem, and my solution was to have a method which hides the navigation bar, which is called after a delay of 0 seconds as follows.

The method that is called is:

```
-(void) hideNavBar {
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method, I have the following:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideNavBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

This works and removes the navigation bar in one instantaneous swoop.  You can amend the delay time if you want the animation or for it to be removed after a delay.  I tried [self hideNavBar] but that simply did not work, so sticking to what I have above.

Hope this helps, and if someone has a more elegant solution, I'm interested!

Comment: Damn this got me for the better part of an hour. Thanks!

Just to clairify, you need to put this in the view controller that is being pushed onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this bugged me for the a couple of hours, but I finally got it to work!  The problem seems to be that the UISearchDisplayController keeps track of whether or not it has hid the navigation bar, and if it has, it restore it, after the view has been dismissed.  That is why with many of the answers above you see the tail end of the animation of the bar hiding itself when the new view is pushed.  However, by tricking the search display controller we can change this behavior.

**First: Subclass The UISearchDisplayController**

Following the answer on how to keep a navigation controller from hiding, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257456/877032), I altered the code, to keep the navigation bar hidden:

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.active == visible)
        return;

    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];

    if (visible)
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    else{
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Note we hide the navbar before we call the super setActive function.  This seems to keep the super class from trying to hide the nav bar and consequently, from trying to restore it ater item selection. Now when the controller becomes active, the bar will be hidden like normal.  Also note that we restore the navigation bar when the searchBar resigns first responder.  This will restore the bar if we cancel out of the controller.

**Second: Hide Navigation Bar When Exiting**

If we hide the navigation bar in the view will disappear, it will be hidden:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

**Third: Hide Navigation Bar When Returning**

The only problem now is that if we select a row from the filtered tableview, when we return, the navigation bar will be visible.  To fix this we need to put a check in view will Appear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(self.isFiltered){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    }

}
```

While this feels like a huge hack, it does the trick and I could see no better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into the same problem, managed to get it working smoothly with this ugly hack:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated 
{
    if (searchController_.active)       
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = nil;        
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
}


- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated 
{       
    if (searchController_.active)       
    {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    }

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: my view has the navigation bar hidden by default and here's the way to keep it hidden:

```
-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews{
  if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
  {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  }
}
```

This way the navigation bar doesn't appear even after the search bar has been used.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL) animated
{
    // self.searchOn property tell if full screen search is enabled
    //if (self.searchOn)
    //{

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    //}

    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
}


- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    //if (self.searchOn)
    //{
         [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    //}

    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```