# setNavigationBarHidden:YES doesn't work with the searchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using the following code to hide my navigationBar in the detailViewController(my second view),
and it works perfectly fine when I tap any of my object from the MasterViewController(my first view).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

However, when I filter the table list in the masterViewController using searchDisplayController
and tap any object from the result, the navigationBar in the detailView doesn't get hidden...

Do I have to do any extra work to hide the navigationBar if I use the searchDisplayController?

for Debug, I set the break point on the line of setNavigationBarHidden:YES, and even if
I go to the detailViewController via search result, the application hits the line..

Comment: if I put [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated]; in viewDidAppear, it works fine... but I want it to be hidden before the second view shows up :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you shuold put [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; in  viewWillLayoutSubviews function.like this:

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this method:
In that controller, where you declared `UISearchController *searchController`, you should implement two methods (only for example):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // if you want to hide Navigation Bar when searchController will become active
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
}
```

The code above may have differences. Main point in `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` property (iOS 8.0 and later). Try to play with it, and turn to `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO` before pushing a new controller. After this manipulations I took profit: when pushed UIViewController, setter `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` become working

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide Navigation bar then, In your MainWindow xib uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" attributes of Navigation Controller.

This Will hide the Navigation Bar in your Whole Project. If you want to Show Navigation Bar in any Controller set NavigationBar Hidden = NO in ViewDidLoad Method of that Controller.

Comment: I implemented the navigationBar programatically, so setNavigationBarHidden is the only option... it doesn't work when I use it from the search result :(

Comment: worked for me , setNavigationBarHidden wasnt working for me from IB.

Answer (score 0):

you should hack search display controller in some way to hide its built in navigationBar.

here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337037/1348121

Answer (score 0):

This

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

causes layout problems, so i used code below. Works fine for me.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```