# How to hide status bar automatically after load view

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

guys,
I want to hide the status bar in the code. After loaded view, the status bar will show and it will automatically hide after a while. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You want `UIApplication`'s `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden%3awithAnimation%3a).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it and there might be a better way but if you put the following in your load view function:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideNavBar) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

and then have this function

```
-(void) hideNavBar {
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

You might have to hide the navigation bar in a view animation block. but some combination should work

Check out
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340399/keeping-uinavigationcontrollers-navigationbar-hidden-after-uisearchdisplaycontr)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it in you AppDelegate, when applicationDidBecommeActive ("After loaded view").
Set hide status after 400ms, with UIView animation block and calculate your root view controller's navigation bar

```
// AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SomeViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeViewController *someViewController;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.someViewController.navigationController.navigationBar;
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                               withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                        animations:^{
                            navBar.frame = CGRectMake(navBar.frame.origin.x, 0, navBar.frame.size.width, navBar.frame.size.height);
                     } completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

that's it, "After loaded view (didBecomeActive), the status bar will show and it will automatically hide after a while (400ms)"

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your project and select `Hide during application launch` inside the header General, section `Deployment Info` like this:

[image]

And inside the info.plist set the `View controller-based status bar` to NO:

[image]